# Subreport (Chart) is being repeated on Main report (Dashboard)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have been on this for days now and I can't seem to get this right.

Scenario:

I have a dashboard with other date like tables etc. But I have 3 sub reports (All charts). When I run the main report it doesn't use the between page break that is in the Sub report. So when I select the customer parameter for 1 person then it works but when I select more then the sub reports preview under each other. I can't put in any page break on the main report, because then the report looses the rest of the report thereafter. Is there anyway to get this sorted?

I have used rectangles and lists. Not sure if the problem in that the dashboard itself is also in a list to group for each instance(Customer), so that Is now the main dataset for the Dashboard. Am I doing something wrong?

So I would like to have 3 dashboards when I choose 3 customers (Parameters). The do not necessarily on different pages but that is what I am trying to do

I have really tried everything I can think of.

Has someone ever come across this? Hope my question makes sense. Sorry for the long msg.

Kind regards
Ruahl

Comment: Stick your main report in a table grouped by the values for the chart. Then send each sub report the value from the group. This should make 3 dashboards and you can page break after groups.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have done as you said. I stuck the main report in a table and grouped it by Consultant. I am not 100% sure what you mean with send each value to the sub report. There are a few data sets in the main report so when I use a table for the report, then I can only make use of one data set (If this makes sense) Can I possible send you something?

Comment: You need to group by the customer parameter and then send the value from the textbox to the sub report.

Comment: Thanks Snowlockk, I have done that. When I group with parameter I get the error msg "The Group expression used in grouping 'Customer' returned a data type that is not valid", but the data type is set to text. When I use Parameters!Customer.Value(0) then it kind of works as I don't get the subreport underneath each other, but when I go to the next page then all the data changes for that customer but the sub report chart only sticks with the value of the first parameter. I'm sorry if I sound stupid but really appreciate the help

Comment: (PS =. Does the sub report also need to be in a table or list and also grouped with the customer parameter and then set the break between instances or does the sub report in the main report have to be in a table a well) Jut want to make sure I have all my ducks in a row before asking any stupid question :)

Answer (score 0):

Stick your main report with the sub report into a new table grouped by the customer parameter. Then in your sub report set the input vale to be the value of the textbox from that grouping.

[image]

Comment: Hi SnowLokk,Thank you, that does works as I tried a smaller report. The problem I am facing is that error I am getting in this report regarding the grouping parameter. "The Group expression used in grouping 'Customer' returned a data type that is not valid" and this does not make sense to me. If I put (0) at the end of the expression then it doesn't give error but also doesn't use the parameters except for the 1st one chosen. Do you know what this could be?